# Problem with simplification

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have an expression that I think should be simplified to zero but Mathematica gives me a weird result. I have

```
Simplify[-2*Sqrt[2*a] + Sqrt[(2^3)*a]]
```

The result given by mathematica is

```
-2 Sqrt[2] (-1 + ) Sqrt[a]
```

When I copied the above line of code from my notebook and pasted it here, the term appearing as `(-1 + )` looked like  `(-1 + \.08)`. Is this of any help to solve the issue?

I'd simply like Mathematica to simplify my expression in a smart way.

EDIT: FullSimplify returns the same output

Comment: it works on V12  screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bzJ8F.png) try on clean kernel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently your input cell contains extraneous characters (you could try FullForm on your input to see where the `\.08` comes from). Retype your equation from scratch  (do **not** copy/paste) in a new cell and execute. It should work.